# How to pass variable to subclass of FlaskForm

Tags: python, flask, flask-wtforms, wtforms

I have a class which is derived from FlaskForm and I need to pass my parameters

```
class User(FlaskForm):    
    def __init__(self, argName, argLastName): 
        super(EditCandidate, self).__init__()
        self.name = argLastName
        self.lastName = argLastName


    name = StringField(default = self.name , validators=[DataRequired(message="Ad xanası doldurulmalıdır."), Length(min=2, max=20, message="Ad min-2, max-20 hərfdən təşkil oluna bilər.")] )
    lastName = StringField(default= self.lastName , validators=[DataRequired(message="Soyad xanası doldurulmalıdır."), Length(min=2, max=20, message="Soyad min-2, max-20 hərfdən təşkil oluna bilər.")] )
```

But Python gives me this error:

```
    name = StringField(default = self.name , validators=[DataRequired(message="Ad xanası doldurulmalıdır."), Length(min=2, max=20, message="Ad min-2, max-20 hərfdən təşkil oluna bilər.")] )
NameError: name 'self' is not defined
```

How to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

`Self` reprents the instance/object of the class and is used to access its attributes and methods.

Your attributes are defined as `self.name` and `self.lastName` and so you can only use the said attributes and not `self.argName`,`self.argLastName`- these are passed as parameters to the function and cannot be accessed outside of the function scope.

Replace them in the `StringField()` call and it should work.

**Edit:**

In this case, this is because the `self` is outside the `init()` method meaning the word itself is not defined if it's used anywhere outside the initialization function. To solve:  indent the name and last name variable so that they appear on the same indent as `self.<>` attributes, as shown below

```
class User(FlaskForm):    
    def __init__(self, argName, argLastName): 
        super(EditCandidate, self).__init__()
        self.name = argLastName
        self.lastName = argLastName

    
        name = StringField(default = self.name , validators=[DataRequired(message="Ad xanası doldurulmalıdır."), Length(min=2, max=20, message="Ad min-2, max-20 hərfdən təşkil oluna bilər.")] )
        lastName = StringField(default= self.lastName , validators=[DataRequired(message="Soyad xanası doldurulmalıdır."), Length(min=2, max=20, message="Soyad min-2, max-20 hərfdən təşkil oluna bilər.")] )
```

Comment: It still doesn't work. Error: name = StringField(default = self.name, validators=[DataRequired(message="Ad xanası doldurulmalıdır."), Length(min=2, max=20, message="Ad min-2, max-20 hərfdən təşkil oluna bilər.")] )
**NameError: name 'self' is not defined**

Comment: See the edit. It can be solved as stated and probably what you are looking for. You can also put those in a method and pass the  `self `as the parameter and initialize it.

Comment: **self** problem will be solved but variables have to be in **class level**.

Comment: What is the need to have in class level - can you explain in a bit detail, i.e. your use case that requires it as such. Typically objects/instances are what is used to access the `FlaskForm`. If it suffices you can define a global level variable and use that.

Comment: @ AzyCrw4282 TypeError: 'UnboundField' object is not callable

Comment: Can you update your new code with the full error trace to the question?